# Getting line of best fit in scatterplot using Mtcars example

Tags: r

Hello how do you get the line of best fit on the Weight vs Milage scatterplot? even though they are kinda dispersed. Below are my codes:

```
plot(x = mtcars$wt,y = mtcars$mpg,
     xlab = "Weight",
     ylab = "Milage",
     xlim = c(2.5,5),
     ylim = c(15,30),        
     main = "Weight vs Milage")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with base R's `plot`, you can do:

```
plot(x = mtcars$wt,y = mtcars$mpg,
 xlab = "Weight",
 ylab = "Milage",
 xlim = c(2.5,5),
 ylim = c(15,30),        
 main = "Weight vs Milage")
abline(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars), col = "red")
```

[image]

Explanation: `lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)` regresses `mpg` on `wt` in a simple linear model; `abline` can take `lm` return objects as input to draw the regression line.

Comment: This is nice. Just a follow up question how do you put this to excel? I tried this code write.xlsx(Scatterplot, file= "Scatterplot.xlsx", sheetName="Scatterplot" ,append=FALSE) but there's an error says out of bounds.

Comment: @Bustergun Not sure what you mean. As far as I know, an R plot won't be editable/customisable within Excel. Why export to Excel? Better to keep everything in R. If you need to share data & results, you can export the data with `write.csv` and then open the file in Excel. Or save the figure as a pdf/png, take a look at `?png` and `?pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = F)
```